# VBA copying from one excel sheet to another excel sheet?

Tags: vba, excel

I am basically copying one excel file sheet to a particular sheet of the excel file(same file as where I am writing the macro).I get the error- Run time error '9': Subscript out of range on the line  WbTarget.Sheets("FPP").Range("A1:E654").PasteSpecial
I am not that good in VBA-any help please?

```
Sub XMLR()
Dim output As String
output = CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Exec("R CMD BATCH  filepath.R").StdOut.ReadAll
Call XML
End Sub

Sub XML()
Dim wbTarget            
Dim wbThis              
Dim strName             
Set wbThis = Workbooks.Open("file.xlsx")
wbThis.Activate
strName = ActiveSheet.Name
Set wbTarget = ActiveWorkbook
Application.CutCopyMode = False
wbThis.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:E654").Copy
wbTarget.Sheets("FPP").Range("A1:E654").PasteSpecial
Application.CutCopyMode = False
wbTarget.Save
wbTarget.Close
wbThis.Close
Set wbTarget = Nothing
Set wbThis = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: Probably means you don't have a sheet of that name in that workbook. Think the problem is that this line `Set wbTarget = ActiveWorkbook` is  the same workbook as that assigned to wbThis. One of them should be referring to ThisWorkbook I guess (the workbook containing the code).

Comment: Are both workbooks (wbThis and wbTarget) supposed to be the same workbook? Those two variables are pointing at the same workbook. If that is intentional, then you are trying to copy from sheet "Sheet1" to sheet "FPP" in the same workbook, right? If that is all correct so far, I would try changing your breaking line to: `WbTarget.Sheets("FPP").Range("A1").PasteSpecial`

Comment: I want to copy from wbthis.sheets(a different excel file) to my current working excel sheet(activeworkbook). Hope this makes it clear. What changes should I make? Wat is the reason for error?

Comment: Ah, so wbThis is meant to be an external workbook? Then try this one: `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FPP").Range("A1").PasteSpecial`

Comment: It works but gives Run Time error "-2147221080': Automation error

Answer (score 0):

Slightly confusing, but try this:

```
Sub XML()

Dim wbTarget As Workbook
Dim wbThis As Workbook
Dim strName As String

Set wbThis = Workbooks.Open("file.xlsx")

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("FPP").Range("A1:E654").Value = wbThis.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:E654").Value

wbTarget.Save
wbTarget.Close
wbThis.Close

Set wbTarget = Nothing
Set wbThis = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that both WbTarget and WbThis refer to the same workbook.

You should change you declaration:

`Set wbTarget = ActiveWorkbook`

to

`Set wbTarget = Application.ThisWorkbook`